# How to get item from list and add EditText with it?

Tags: java, android, list, android-edittext

I am working with androidstudio, API lvl Oreo

I want to make a list of ingredients from which user can choose, every time the item is chosen, we will get it's name and edit text field next to it to enter the number of this ingredient.

For example:

```
Ingredients Strength Defense Stamina
      Ing 1        2       0       3
      Ing 2        1       1       4
      Ing 3        2       4       1
```

Thats my data, i want user to choose items from 1st column after that it will get listed below with edittext field next to it

```
(+) Button (after clicking it user will search list and select ingredient)

Ing1        (EditText) 2
Ing3        (EditText) 1

(=) Button (Summs ingredients values, in that case user will get +6 Strength, +4 
Defense and +7 Stamina)
```

After that i send the stats to the next activity with intent

Questions

1. How do i make that (+) button work, to do both - Choose item and also add a EditText field?
2. Can i limit user to enter only integer values into edittext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer 1:

> How do i make that (+) button work, to do both - Choose item and also add a EditText field?

All you need to do is to tinker with the XML of your layout. Instead of the (+) button you can make every point of the list a child to a radioButton, so the user will be able to select only one ingredient at a time. If you want the EditText field to appear when user selects the radioButton, you neeed to search through the properties of radioButton and find something like `onSelect` property and make it change the `visible` and `editable` property of the EditText.

### Answer 2:

> Can i limit user to enter only integer values into edittext?

You can not make the EditText field accept only letter input, but you can for example make it change it's color to red when it detects a letter in it. So you can search EditText properties for something called `onInput`, `onFocus` or `onEnter` and make a method that checks if the input contains only numbers.

**EDIT:** If you want to avoid using radioButton, you can:

- Make the radioButton look like a normal button
- Use normal buttons and code their onClick() functions that way so clicking them will turn off every other button's editText

I would suggest you using the second option, but the first one will be easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer i might check this out if i wont find other way
I still would prefer avoid using radiobutton